# How to Insert LinkLabel into DataGridViewCell C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewlinkcolumn

Trying to find a way to create a DataGridViewCell that supports multiple links, like this:

[Multiple Links in a GridView Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRMMy.png)

I know this has been asked a thousand times (I've spent a day combing through them), but please hear me out. I would like one cell to contain multiple links separated by commas. I have found a way to do this with a LinkLabel:

```
var addresses = new List<string>
{
    "http://www.example.com/page1",
    "http://www.example.com/page2",
    "http://www.example.com/page3",
};

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var links = new List<LinkLabel.Link>();

foreach (var address in addresses)
{
    if (stringBuilder.Length > 0) stringBuilder.Append(", ");

    // We cannot add the new LinkLabel.Link to the LinkLabel yet because
    // there is no text in the label yet, so the label will complain about
    // the link location being out of range. So we'll temporarily store
    // the links in a collection and add them later.
    links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link(stringBuilder.Length, address.Length, address));
    stringBuilder.Append(address);
}

// We must set the text before we add the links.
linkLabel1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
foreach (var link in links)
{
    linkLabel1.Links.Add(link);
}
linkLabel1.AutoSize = true;
linkLabel1.LinkClicked += (s, e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)e.Link.LinkData);
};
```

[LinkList with Multiple Links Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrRML.png)

I cannot find a way to add this LinkList to a DataGridViewCell. Is it possible to somehow insert this LinkLabel into a DataGridViewCell and still have it function correctly? Or can this same functionality somehow be obtained by using a DataGridViewLinkColumn somehow?

Comment: See: [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx) and substitute LinkLabel for the NumericUpDown.

Comment: I'm attempting this, and it is intense. Also, painting simple text like this custom cell does is not as difficult as handling multiple links. Maybe I'm just in over my head here.